# render result is pixelated (or: has lower resolution that it should)

Tags: javascript, three.js, webgl

I'm doing some prototyping, and I'm displaying some data in 3D using `three.js` (version 68). Desired result of whole animation would be a bunch of colored balls (that represent protons and neutrons that are colored according to some schema). Everything works good, but for reasons unknown to me rendered results are pixcelated.

Current version basically looks like that (this image is ~400px wide): [image: Result example]

I have checked all obvious things like: passing incorrect resolution, browser scaling and so forth.

You can see this issue on [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tmYXJ/4/), and download the [webpage here](https://s3.amazonaws.com/public-bucket-vzi0CDPFDE4ywJfvfylfpnDW/static.zip).

And also here are revelant parts of code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head lang="en">
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <script src="js/jquery.js"></script>
    <script src="js/coffee-script.js"></script>
    <script src="js/three.js"></script>
    <script src="js/OrbitControls.js"></script>
    <script src="js/animtest/load_event.js"></script>
    <style>canvas { width: 100%; height: 100% }</style>
    <title></title>

</head>
<body>
<div id="animation"
    style="width: 1024px; height: 768px; ">

</div>
<script>
    $(function(){
       ctrl = new AnimController("#animation");
       ctrl.set_up_scene();
       ctrl.render();
       ctrl.display_frame(4);
    });
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Here is the coffeescript code that loads the animation:

```
class AnimController

  ...

  set_up_scene: () ->
    @scene = new THREE.Scene()
    el = $(@element_name)
    @camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(45
      el.width()/el.height(),
      1, 20000
    )
    @camera.position.set(100, 100, 0)
    @scene.add new THREE.AmbientLight 0x111111

    @renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer()
    el.html(@renderer.domElement)
    controls = new THREE.OrbitControls(@camera, @renderer.domElement );
    controls.addEventListener 'change', () =>
      console.log("Change")
      @render()

  render: () ->
    requestAnimationFrame(() => @render)
    console.log "Render"
    if @update_scene
      material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial() #"color": 0xffff00,
      geometry = new THREE.SphereGeometry 5, 50, 50
      console.log "Update"
      @update_scene = false
      @scene = new THREE.Scene()
      for particle in @curr_event
        p = particle['position']
        sphere = new THREE.Mesh( geometry, material );
        sphere.position.set(p[0], p[1], p[2])
        @scene.add(sphere)
    @renderer.render(@scene, @camera)
```

Comment: Don't now coffeescript but you are rendering with the renderer that is not antialiased. Why are you allocating two rendereres?

Comment: That was it. Renderer was not antialiased (other bug was that I forgot about @). If you' ll turn this to an answer I'll accept it.

Comment: Ech. Error was that I didn't call: ``renderer.setSize( el.width(), el.height() )`` on the renderer that was used by three.js.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Antialiasing also was a factor (see @gaitat answer) but I also forgot to set resoluion the renderer:

```
renderer.setSize( 1024, 768 )
```

Answer (score 10):

It seems that you have not requested antialiasing on the renderer you are using. I don't know coffeescript but in javascript you would do:

```
 renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({ antialias: true });
```

Comment: At least for three.js, the correct attribute is `antialias`, not `antialiasing`